# ¿Como añadir multiples permisos de usuarios a mi login en PHP?

Tags: php, login

Hola estoy modificando un login que me encontré en un videtutorial solo quiero aparte de validar el nombre de usuario y contraseña validar campos de permisos de la base de datos, en este caso estoy tratando de agregar un campo llamado editar_coa el cual ya logre agregar en la variable de sesión es mas puedo imprimirlo con un echo pero no encuentro como hacer que solo si ese campo vale 1 se muestre la parte del contenido de editar, nota en mi código planeo agregar múltiples permisos.

```
    <?php
$page_title = "User Authentication - Homepage";
include_once 'partials/headers.php';

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM capturar_pedido ORDER BY id_pedido");


?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="flag">
        <h1>Sistema de autenticacion</h1>



        <?php if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']))): ?>
            <P class="lead">No has iniciado sesión <a href="login.php">Inicia sesión</a>
                </P>

        <?php else: ?>


            <p class="lead">Has iniciado sesión como <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo $_SESSION['username'];
                echo $_SESSION['editar_coa'];//imprime correctamente el valor de un campo llamado editar_coa el cual es del tipo enum
                ?>



        <a href="capturarpedidos.php">Hacer un nuevo pedido</a><br/><br/>

                <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table-bordered table-striped">

    <tr>
        <th>cliente</th>
        <th>orden_de_compra</th>
        <th>producto</th>
        <th>unidad</th>
                <th>cantidad</th>
                <th>fecha_de_embarque</th>
        <th>notas</th>
        <th>etiquetado</th>

        <th>opciones</th>
                <th>Formulario salida de materiales</th>

        <th>salida de materiales</th>
                <th>Formulario Coa</th>


        <th>Coa</th>


    </tr>
    <?php   
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['cliente']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['orden_de_compra']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['producto']."</td>";   
                echo "<td>".$row['unidad']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row['cantidad']."</td>";   
        echo "<td>" . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['fecha_de_embarque'])) . "</td>";

        echo "<td>".$row['notas']."</td>";  
        echo "<td>".$row['etiquetado']."</td>"; 

        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id_pedido=$row[id_pedido]\">Editar</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id_pedido=$row[id_pedido]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>"; 
                echo "<td><a href=\"formulariosalidademateriales.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Salida de materiales</a></td>";

        echo "<td><a href=\"pdfsalidademateriales.php?orden_de_compra=$row[orden_de_compra]\">Salida de materiales</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"formulariocoatorustrading.php?id_pedido=$row[id_pedido]\">Coa</a></td>";

        echo "<td><a href=\"pdfcoa.php?id_pedido=$row[id_pedido]\">Coa</a></td>";

    }
    ?>
    </table>
        </div>


        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include_once 'partials/footers.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso deberias tratarlo en la bbdd. Si cierto usuario tiene permiso para ver X apartado que devuelva un "OK" o por ejemplo ["mensajesprivados":1]. Luego tratas esa respuesta para decidir mostrarlo o no.

Comment: Creo que no está muy claro lo que preguntas. Cual es tu duda? como poner los checkbox?

Comment: @Sergio1871 Mi duda es aqui en esta parte en ningun momento veo el acceso a la tabla con el id para comprobar si ese registro por ejemplo tiene el campo editar activado o lo que es lo mismo en 1, en lugar de 0 <?php if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']))): ?>

Comment: @GDP No es mas complicado en la bd? el sistema de sesion ya esta inicia y guarda la sesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el momento lo estoy resolviendo así aunque no entiendo porque no me funcionaba usando isset

```
  <?php
    if($_SESSION['editar_coa']== 1 ) {
    ?>
<p>Aqui va el contenido</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Si perdona es que escribir desde el movil es jodido, era con dos = no con uno, entonces lo que necesitas seria `<php if($_SESSION['editar_coa]):?> // codoigo htm <php else:?> //otro codigo <php endif;?>`

Comment: @GamboaYGB Hola descuida se que es incomodo escribir desde un movil, este ultimo codigo que me has pasado veo que tampoco valida si el campo es igual a 1 o como funcionaria para diferenciar quien tiene permiso o no? Cual seria la diferencia con mi codigo actual? mi idea es poner multiples permisos

Answer (score 1):

Crea un canpo tinity en la base de datos que te almacene 0 o 1 segun lo que seleccione en  checkbox, y cuando busques el usuario crea una variable de session en plan `$_SESSION['privilegio]=priv`
Priv tendria el valor que devuelve la base de dato, y luego con una condicion decides si hace cosas o no `if(isset($_SESSION['privilegio']){
    if($_SESSION['privilegio']=0):
       //hago lo quebquiera
  }`

Y luego en ek logout destruyes la var de session, algo mas o menos asi seria

Comment: Hola amigo ya agregue un campo llamado editar_coa, tu respuesta me ha ayudado cree la variable de sesion, incluso logro imprimirla en mi pagina index.php el maldito problema es no logro hacer el if para restringir cierta parte del codigo, podrias checar mi codigo y corregirme, ya lo actualize por cierto noto que en tu codigo dentro de la condicion has puesto un solo signo '='  y ese es el operador de asignar